# Should unit tests in Test Explorer connect to a database?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, test-explorer

Should unit tests in Test Explorer connect to a database?

I can execute the same code outside of the test case and it correctly inserts into the database.  When trying to test the repository (that performs the insert) within a unit test written in Visual Studio test explorer, the insert does not happen.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want people to give their opinion on whether you should write to the database, or do you want to know why it didn't work?

Comment: Opinions and recommendations - which now reading the comments I understand there shouldn't be any CRUD in a unit test. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unit tests are supposed to test your business layer logic/methods. It should not be inserting to the database. You should be using a fake data access layer( Use a mocking library like Moq / FakeItEasy) if needed.

A quick example using Moq library.

```
var repoMoq = new Mock<IRepository>();
repoMoq.Setup(s=>s.GetStudentName(It.IsAny<int>)).Returns("Test Student");
var bl = new StudentManagementBusinessLayerClass(repoMoq.Object);
// To do : Assert Something now.
// Ex : bl.GetStudent(234);
```

Here you are mocking your Data access layer,IRepository's `GetStudentMethod` to return "TestStudent" when it is being called from the Unit test.

End to end Integration tests are the one you need where you execute a full cycle which inserts data to db and once your testing is done, Delete /Rollback the test data.

Comment: Another thing is that if you want to make sure your `Insert` functions are getting called, look in to Moq's `Verify` functionality rather than inserting into your database directly. Mock out the dependencies, then verify that the proper methods are getting called.